# UINavigationController root view (iOS)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, rootview

```
[PersonListNav pushViewController:plist animated:FALSE];Hi there! :) Googling this has returned no luck...
```

In short, I have UINavigationController (Named PersonListNav) which is instantiated inside of my main xib...

I also have a custom view controller named plist.

I call:

```
[PersonListNav pushViewController:plist animated:FALSE];
```

In my app delegate's didFinishLauchingWithOptions method.

It works fine! Except for one thing... There is a back button entitled "Root View Controller". So I thought "Okay, IB must be pushing its own empty view for me, all I need to do is pop that first..."

I tried the following code:

```
[PersonListNav popViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
[PersonListNav pushViewController:plist animated:FALSE];
```

To find that the same exact thing was happening.

As a final test, I tried reversing the two calls!

```
[PersonListNav pushViewController:plist animated:FALSE];
[PersonListNav popViewControllerAnimated:FALSE];
```

THAT works as I would expect -- the plist view controller never shows up -- This "Root View Controller" is the currently displayed view.

So, that is my dilemma, it would appear that I cannot pop this Root View Controller off of my stack, to replace it with something else! How would you go about programmatically making plist the root controller?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
When you init `PersonListNav`

Do the following

```
//set root view controller to plist controller
PersonListNav *nav = [PersonListNav initWithRootViewController:plist];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to pull off the same effect while still instantiating PersonListNav inside my MainWindow xib? That is what is causing my problem, and I'm wondering if it's even possible to initialize navigationConrollers inside of the xib without running into this problem

Comment: UINavigationController are normally initialized by code, i never initialize it by xib, i cant answer your question right now, ill do some research and get back to you :) also, if it was helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer :)

Comment: Thankyou :) I'm doing an iOS programming course, and they said I could either instantiate the navigationControlelr inside my xib, or through code. Out of curiosity I decided to try the xib approach, but it appears that it is now less than possible. It's an older course, I suspect there has been a change int the API which causes the xib to load using initWithRootViewController, instead of a simple init, but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

In your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions you are creating your navigationController with the rootViewController but you can just create that with your custom view controller and you will never need the rootViewController. Are you using the default code it sets up for you?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your answer, I never actually create the navigationController -- It is instantiated in my main xib

Comment: Oh well if you have it all in IB then you just need to have it not referencing your rootviewcontroller. The easiest way to do it is in code but otherwise you will have to remove the connection to the rootviewcontroller and add in your plist controller as there root of the navigationcontroller